# Calculating the area of a shape

Tags: java, area

Prompt the user to choose between a shape. correct information about the chosen shape. Calculate the area of the shape to four decimal places. Ask the user if they would like to choose another shape; continue until the user chooses to stop. Please Help me understand my error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1_CSC110 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String PlayAgain= "";

    int circle = 1;
    int square = 2;
    int rectangle = 3;
    int righttriangle = 4;
    int amount;

    do {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Circle \t\t 1\nSquare \t\t 2\n rectangle \t\3\rightAngle \t4\n");
        System.out.print("Enter number to choose shape");

        amount = scan.nextInt();
        if (amount == circle) {

            double radius;
            double areacircle;

            System.out.println("Shape chose = Circle");
            System.out.print("Enter Radius");

            radius = scan.nextDouble();
            areacircle = Math.PI * (radius * radius);

            System.out.println("Area=" + areacircle);
        }
        if (amount == square){
            double sidelength;
            double areasquare;

            System.out.println("\nShape chosen = Square");
            System.out.print("Enter width");

            sidelength = scan.nextDouble();
            areasquare = sidelength * sidelength;

            System.out.println("Area =" + areasquare);
        }

        if (amount == rectangle) {

            double width;
            double length;
            double arearectangle;

            System.out.println("\nShape chosen = Rectangle");

            System.out.print("Enter width:");
            width = scan.nextDouble();


            System.out.print("Enter length:");
            length = scan.nextDouble();

            arearectangle = length * width;
            System.out.println("Area =" + arearectangle);
        }

        if (amount == righttriangle) {
            double Aleg;
            double Bleg;
            double arearighttriangle;

            System.out.println("\nShape chosen = Right Triangle");

            System.out.print("Enter leg A of triangle");
            Aleg = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter leg B of triangle");
            Bleg = scan.nextDouble();

            arearighttriangle = .5 * Aleg * Bleg;
            System.out.println("Area =" + arearighttriangle);
        }
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to chose another shape? Yes/No");
        PlayAgain = scan.next();

        While (PlayAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
        if (PlayAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));{
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }}
    private static void While(boolean equalsIgnoreCase) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include what error you got

Answer (score 0):

You messed up at the end of the do...while-loop. It should be:

```
do
{
  //....
  System.out.println("\nWould you like to chose another shape? Yes/No");
  PlayAgain = scan.next();
}while(PlayAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
System.out.println("Bye!");
```